# Regarding wait and notify

Tags: java

I was developing the simple code related to wait & notify I have created two seprate classes , below are the classes

```
    class ThreadA {
 public static void main(String [] args) {
 Thread b = new Thread();
 b.start();

 synchronized(b) {
 try {
 System.out.println("Waiting for b to complete...");
 b.wait();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {}
 //System.out.println("Total is: " + b.totals);
 }
}
}

and the other one is ...





class ThreadB extends Thread {
public  int totals;

 public void run() {
     synchronized(this) {
     for(int i=0;i<100;i++) {
      totals += i;
      }
      notify();
      }
      }
     }
```

but inside class ThreadA, I am getting the complie time error when I am accessing the totals from b thread object that is ..

```
System.out.println("Total is: " + b.totals);
```

Please advise me how to correct it so that I can execute my code..!! thanks in advance ..!1

Comment: Although the answer has already been discovered. Future questions could be improved by including the actual error message encountered.

Comment: And also when you post code, make sure of the identation

Answer (score 6):

This is the immediate problem:

```
Thread b = new Thread();
```

You're never actually creating an instance of `ThreadB`. The type of `b` is only `Thread`, not `ThreadB` which is why the compiler can't resolve the `totals` identifier

Additionally:

- Public fields are a really bad idea - use properties instead
- Calling `wait` and `notify` on a `Thread` is a very bad idea, as the `Thread` class itself calls `wait` and `notify`.
- You should usually implement `Runnable` instead of extending `Thread`, for better separation of concerns.
- It would generally be better to call something on your class which knew to synchronize on a monitor which is *only* visible to that code, rather than synchronizing (and waiting for) a publicly visible monitor. It makes it easier to reason about your threading.

Comment: Concerning the last point, `b` as declared is not publicly visible.It is in the scope of `main` and not a public member of `ThreadA`.May be I missunderstand your note on this?

Comment: @user384706: I mean that synchronizing on *anything* which code outside the class itself has access to (including `this`) is a bad idea. `ThreadB` can't possibly know how wide-spread references to instances of it might be.

Comment: @JonSkeet "Calling wait and notify on a Thread is a very bad idea, as the Thread class itself calls wait and notify." Can you explain this a  bit ?

Comment: @Geek: Basically what I said - other bits of Java will *also* be calling `wait` and `notify` on `Thread` objects, which will interfere with any calls you make on it. Wherever possible, lock, wait and notify on an object which *only* your code knows about.

Comment: +Jon +1 for the explanation .